# Using react-virtualized InfiniteLoader

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

Does react-virtualized's `InfiniteLoader` require seed data to function? The following is my component:

```
class Bookmarks extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.loaded = {
            cursor: null,
            data: []
        };

        this._isRowLoaded = this._isRowLoaded.bind(this);
        this._loadMoreRows = this._loadMoreRows.bind(this);
        this._rowRenderer = this._rowRenderer.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        const size = this.loaded.data.length;

        return (
            <InfiniteLoader
                isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
                loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
                rowCount={size}>
                {({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) =>
                    <AutoSizer>
                        {({width, height}) =>
                            <List
                                ref={registerChild}
                                height={height}
                                onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                                rowCount={size}
                                rowHeight={30}
                                rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
                                width={width}
                            />}
                    </AutoSizer>}
            </InfiniteLoader>
        );
    }

    _isRowLoaded({index}) {
        return !!this.loaded.data[index];
    }

    _loadMoreRows({startIndex, stopIndex}) {
        fetch('/api/bookmarks').then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {
            this.loaded = {
                cursor: json.cursor,
                data: this.loaded.data.push(...json.data),
            };
        });
    }

    _rowRenderer({index, key, style}) {
        return (
            <div key={key} style={style}>{this.loaded.data[index]}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

In `render()`, `size` is initially zero as there's no data yet, and I assume the component would call `_loadMoreRows`—apparently not.

This is what I thought to be the flow of logic (which is incorrect):

1. Component is created
2. `_loadMoreRows` is called (1st time)
3. When the promise returned by `_loadMoreRows` is resolved, check each loaded rows with `_isRowLoaded`
4. Render each row

Answer (score 3):

> In `render()`, `size` is initially zero as there's no data yet, and I assume the component would call `_loadMoreRows`

This is the key to the misunderstanding. `InfiniteLoader` needs to know if there is more data to *potentially* load. The docs have a couple of simple recipes for working with `InfiniteLoader`:

- If you know the total number of remote records then look at [this example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#examples).
- If you only know if there's at least 1 more record/page to be loaded,
  look at [this example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md).

Comment: Hi can you explain how resetLoadMoreRowsCache is is supposed to be used when filter data updates the underlying set for InfiniteLoader? The documentation is only a few lines and I cannot seem to get InfiniteLoader to call loadMoreRows initially but it is fired after I subsequently scroll?

Comment: Having the same issue. Look forward to sharing a solution